# The value inserted on table is always "null"; the both values passed to timediff() is a timedate(6)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, variables

I think it should get a value of format datetime(). What is the error?

```
CREATE 
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `check` 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON `whatstore` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    declare last_insert_time datetime(6);
    declare new_insert_time datetime(6);
    set @last_insert_time=(select insert_time 
                           from whatstore 
                           order by id desc limit 1);    
    select timediff(new.insert_time,@last_inserted_time) into @new_insert_time;
    case when @new_insert_time > 1 
         then insert into `delete`.table3(time_diff)  
              values (@new_inserted_time);
         else insert into `delete`.table3(time_diff)  
              values(@new_inserted_time);
    end case;
END
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the logic is support to be doing.

Comment: I think you just need to fix variables. For example, you use `set @last_insert_time=(select insert_time from whatstore order by id desc limit 1);` but later reference `@last_inserted_time` notice `@last_insert_time` vs. `@last_inserted_time`

Comment: 1) `last_insert_time` and `@last_insert_time` are TWO **DIFFERENT** VARIABLES.  2) Compare TIMEDIFF() result with integer is strange 3) Execute the same query both in THEN and in ELSE is strange.